Load bearing post slightly rotated/shifted. Will this be a problem?



As in the pictures, support post has shifted/rotated a bit and developed checks/cracks. Will this be a problem and if so how should this be addressed? If the post has to be replaced at some point, it will be a major and costly project?
Also i am not sure what has caused this. I might have leaned weight on it while wearing shoes, etc, is this at all possible to cause a problem like this or something like this can happen on its own?
Edit: spoke to a contractor, plan to rotate the post back and make it plumb, add column cap to top and post base bracket on the bottom, and possibly add another post a feet apart to it to strengthen the support since there appears to be an enhanced slab that studs sit on nearby.

Are you positive it has moved/rotated since being placed?  If it moved by you leaning on it, it is not a support post.  Even using/being shot out of the Royal Canadian Air Farce chicken cannon should not move it.

Yes very certain it has moved. Leaning on it while putting shoes on say daily basis might have chance of causing this? My brother also lives in the house, so just guessing that might have happened. Will have to ask him in a couple of days once he’s back from a trip. Besides this, is this any structural problem that i need to worry about?

If moving by leaning on it, it is not supporting the beam.  Can hammer some slims between the post and beam to tighten it up.

I bet it's just twisted as it's dried out over time.  Seems odd for it not to be securely fastened at the top though.

A big piece of wood like that post will twist and get checks and cracks over time.
The important thing is it can't be bearing much of a load if it moves when leaned on.  I believe it is a needed post but not bearing a load.
You should get it plumb, (best as you can) and add shims between the top of the post and the beam over it. Add a few nails driven up into the beam to help keep it in place.

Thanks for the input, i tried to push it back in place but it has no give at all. Just messaged a contractor, will figure out how much involved the fix will be. I asked around and general census is that unless i backed into it with a car (just moved and ton of stuff to get rid of, so yet to park the car in the garage), a load bearing post won’t easily shift.

If you use an engineer's hammer or similar, can you knock it back into place?  (Don't really go to town on it.)  If not, it's probably not going to move by itself.  Just monitor it and if it gets out of whack in the "inches" range, then you can start worrying.

It may be a pretty wrap around the member that is really carrying the load. If so. I agree with others that its shifting a bit is harmless and not particularly surprising.

Thanks, the wraps around are hvac, so those aren’t really load bearing. the post in question is supporting a beam that runs along the length (as opposed to width) of the ceiling of my garage, and the next post is somewhat far in between…i will see if i have luck with having someone rotate it back in place and somehow reinforce it..
